# how to make sure that the value in a dynamic textbox is not empty using javascript

Tags: asp.net

I have nearly 80 textbox controls being created dynamically on the change of a dropdownlist item.

I need to make sure that none of these textboxes are empty when the user clicks on add item button.

I am aware of document.getElementbyid , however it does not serve my purpose as I will not know the id of the textboxes. The ids of the textboxes created start with "txt".

Can anyone paste a sample code of how to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using jQuery at all?  What have you tried?  The answer seems pretty simple but I'll wait to see what you have tried that isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function validateInput() {
     var inputControls = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
     for(var i = 0; i < inputControls.length; i++) {
          var c = inputControls[i];
          if(c.id && c.id.substring(0, 3) === 'txt' && c.value === '') return false;
     }
     return true;
}
```

Attach this to the `submit` handler or whatever appropriate handler.